# How to put a row in a table with no column division but the rest of the table to have divisions

Tags: tables

I want to make a table where it is completely gridded up apart from the line subscript where I want to have just lines above and below but no other lines.

I am trying this code but it doesn't give me what I want.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption*{Common Notation}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
{\bf Symbol} & {\bf  Description} & {\bf Units} \\ \hline
$\alpha$ & Thermal expansion coefficient & $^\circ$C$^{-1}$ \\ \hline
$\kappa$ & Thermal diffusivity &  m$^2$/s \\ \hline
$\eta$ & Dynamic viscosity & Pa s \\ \hline
$\nu$ & Kinematic viscosity & m$^2$/s \\ \hline
C$_{p}$ & Specific Heat Capacity & J/kg$^\circ$C \\ \hline
$\rho$ & Density & kg/m$^3$ \\ \hline
T & Temperature & $^\circ$C \\ \hline
k & Thermal conductivity & W/m$^\circ$C \\ \hline
v & Velocity & m/yr \\ \hline
$\Delta$T=T$_h$-T$_\infty$ & Temperature Difference & $^\circ$C \\ \hline
$\eta$$^*$=$\eta$$_h$-$\eta$$_\infty$ & Viscosity Contrast & Pa s \\ \hline
U & Speed & m/s \\ \hline
y$_T$ & Thermal boundary layer & m \\ \hline
l$_c$ & Plume height after about 2 hours & m \\ \hline
$\tau$$_c$ & Diffusion time & s \\ \hline
$\tau$ & Time the plume first emerges & s \\ \hline
g & Gravitational acceleration & m/s$^2$ \\ \hline
D & Plume Diameter & m \\ \hline
H & Height of the tank &\\ \hline
P & Pressure & Pa \\
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|} subscript \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
h & Heater  & \\ \hline
$\infty$ & Ambient & \\ \hline
b & Buoyancy & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\label{corn}
\end{table}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for `\multicolumn{}{}{}`??

Comment: I am looking for the easiest way to make the subscript line have no divisions.

Comment: I did try multicolumn but couldnt get it to work properly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

What you want looks like `\multicolumn{}{}{}`

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    something & something & something\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{very very long line}\\
    \hline
    something & something & something\\
    \hline
    something & something & something\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

gives you a table like this:

[image]

As you can see the first `{}` determines how many columns should be put together. The second `{}` stands for the format of those cells and the third one if for the actual content.

Instead of using a new `tabular` environment you can simply replace it with this `\multicolimn` line and get what you want.

Your full Example should look like this after applying those changes:

```
\begin{table}[!ht] 
\centering 
\caption{Common Notation} 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline 
{\bf Symbol} & {\bf Description} & {\bf Units} \\
\hline 
$\alpha$ & Thermal expansion coefficient & $^\circ$C$^{-1}$ \\
\hline 
$\kappa$ & Thermal diffusivity & m$^2$/s \\
\hline 
$\eta$ & Dynamic viscosity & Pa s \\
\hline 
$\nu$ & Kinematic viscosity & m$^2$/s \\
\hline 
$C_{p}$ & Specific Heat Capacity & J/kg$^\circ$C \\
\hline 
$\rho$ & Density & kg/m$^3$ \\
\hline 
T & Temperature & $^\circ$C \\
\hline 
k & Thermal conductivity & W/m$^\circ$C \\
\hline 
v & Velocity & m/yr \\
\hline 
$\Delta$T=T$h$-T$\infty$ & Temperature Difference & $^\circ$C \\
\hline 
$\eta$$^*$=$\eta$$h$-$\eta$$\infty$ & Viscosity Contrast & Pa s \\
\hline 
U & Speed & m/s \\ \hline 
y$_T$ & Thermal boundary layer & m \\
\hline 
l$_c$ & Plume height after about 2 hours & m \\
\hline 
$\tau$$_c$ & Diffusion time & s \\
\hline 
$\tau$ & Time the plume first emerges & s \\
\hline 
g & Gravitational acceleration & m/s$^2$ \\
\hline 
D & Plume Diameter & m \\
\hline 
H & Height of the tank & \\
\hline 
P & Pressure & Pa \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{subscript} \\
\hline
h & Heater & \\ 
\hline 
$\infty$ & Ambient & \\ 
\hline 
b & Buoyancy & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\label{corn} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After ages of searching you have solved my problem!

Comment: @Rico we got the same idea. Should I remove my answer since it is less general than yours?

Comment: you can if you wan't but you don't have to since it is not wrong. @Marie still needs to choose what helped her best by marking it as accepted :)

Comment: There is a typo. multicolimn -> multicolumn